# PHP web service, sending xml data in large size

Tags: php, web-services

Bellow given is my task.

I have a an application developed in codeigniter,the application always getting data from their customers through web service. In most cases the data (xml) will be large in size. Here is where I got stuck. How do I can send these lead data to the server through web service. I planned to implement it using REST web service

One option is read the xml data and send the content as parameter along with the request.
Like...

```
$xmlfile = "leads.xml";
$xmlRaw = file_get_contents($xmlfile);

include 'RestClient.class.php';

$url = "http://localhost/apps/index/";
$ex = RestClient::post($url,array('requestType' =>'sendLead',
                                                        'username' => $name,
                                                         'pass' =>$pass,
                                                         'leadXML'=>$xmlRaw));
```

### But in the case of large file, I dont think it would work fine..

Another option is something like this...

```
Client side                                                                          server
------------------                                                                  --------------------

// send a request to the server with xml file name             

rest::sendLeads("leads.xml"){                                  |    sendLeads(){
                                                               |
                                                               |     $filename =$this->post('filename');
}                                                              |  // calling a client side function and collecting the xml data
                                                               | $xmldata =  getdata($filename);
                                                               |        }
getdata(filename){                                             |

reading xml content and send back it to the server

return $xmldata;
}
```

Is it possible to implement something like this. here we dont need to send the content as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should to use cron on the server every 5(?) minutes?
On the client side you will send last parsed data.
[cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)